# Вырезать последнее слово linux

Tags: linux

У меня есть текст (многострочный, на кириллице). Каким образом (не используя awk) можно вырезать последнее слово в каждой строке и вывести их в терминал или в файл?

P.S.: попросили уточнить. Удалить последнее слово в каждой строке и вывести все их (удалённые слова) в терминале

Comment: 1. «вырезать последнее слово» здесь что означает? «удалить последнее слово» или «удалить всё кроме последнего слова»? 2. символы, входящие в «слово», надо всё-таки уточнить. или наоборот: символы, не входящие в «слово». // внесите необходимые уточнения в текст вопроса, пожалуйста, нажав [edit]

Comment: Удалить последнее слово в каждой строке и вывести все их (удалённые слова) в терминале

Comment: *Удалить последнее слово в каждой строке и вывести все их (удалённые слова) в терминале* — ох. плохо сформулировано. всё равно можно понять и так и эдак (о чём свидетельствуют два ответа, отличающихся именно этим моментом, второй, правда, уже исправлен на противоположное). почему бы не выразиться конкретнее: «удалить всё кроме последнего слова»? и символы, [не] составляющие «слово» вы так и не уточнили. тут могут быть неоднозначности.

Comment: Как видите, люди и без нереальных уточнений поняли вопрос. А ваши комментарии больше похожи на "разрешите докопаться"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 cat file.txt
```

---

```
 The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

 Beautiful is better than ugly.
 Explicit is better than implicit.
 Simple is better than complex.
 Complex is better than complicated.
 Flat is better than nested.
 Sparse is better than dense.
 Readability counts.
```

---

```
sed 's/[^ ]*$//' file.txt  > file.2.txt
```

---

```
 cat file2.txt

 The Zen of Python, by Tim 

 Beautiful is better than 
 Explicit is better than 
 Simple is better than 
 Complex is better than 
 Flat is better than 
 Sparse is better than 
 Readability
```

---

```
 grep -oE '[^ ]+$' file.txt > file3.txt
```

---

```
 cat file3.txt 

 Peters
 ugly.
 implicit.
 complex.
 complicated.
 nested.
 dense.
 counts.
```

---

Comment: Как насчёт `\w$`? На самом деле можно ещё добавить `^\w` перед `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Файл для примера:

```
python -m this > testfile && cat testfile
```

> ```
> The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
> Explicit is better than implicit.
> Simple is better than complex.
> Complex is better than complicated.
> Flat is better than nested.
> Sparse is better than dense.
> Readability counts.
> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
> Although practicality beats purity.
> Errors should never pass silently.
> Unless explicitly silenced.
> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
> Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
> Now is better than never.
> Although never is often better than *right* now.
> If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
> If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
> ```

Возможно, не самый лучший вариант: разворачиваем строку, разбиваем ее по пробельному символу, берем первое слово, разворачиваем обратно. Так как в этом примере есть знаки препинания, удаляем их.

```
rev testfile | cut -d " " -f1 | rev | tr -d ".!"
```

> ```
> Peters
>
> ugly
> implicit
> complex
> complicated
> nested
> dense
> counts
> rules
> purity
> silently
> silenced
> guess
> it
> Dutch
> never
> now
> idea
> idea
> those
> ```

Comment: Интересный способ! Спасибо за подсказку, всё работает

Answer (score 1):

### `grep` и `tr`

Русская классика:

```
$ cat testfile 
Белеет парус одинокой
В тумане моря голубом!..
Что ищет он в стране далекой?
Что кинул он в краю родном?...

Играют волны — ветер свищет,
И мачта гнется и скрыпит...
Увы! он счастия не ищет
И не от счастия бежит!

Под ним струя светлей лазури,
Над ним луч солнца золотой...
А он, мятежный, просит бури,
Как будто в бурях есть покой!
```

`grep` выделяет последнее непустое слово:

```
$ cat testfile | grep -o '[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*$'
одинокой
голубом!..
далекой?
родном?...
свищет,
скрыпит...
ищет
бежит!
лазури,
золотой...
бури,
покой!
```

`tr` отрезает знаки препинания и пробелы в конце строки:

```
$ cat testfile | grep -o '[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*$' | tr -d [:punct:][:blank:]
одинокой
голубом
далекой
родном
свищет
скрыпит
ищет
бежит
лазури
золотой
бури
покой
```

Comment: Со второго примера и далее `cat` Не нужен.